# Can cabbage leaf (stalk leaf not the outer leaf) be eaten?

Tags: food-safety, cabbage

I am growing [white cabbages](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Cabbage.jpg) and as the cabbage heart develops there are other leaves growing below the heart off the main plant stalk.  Can these leaves be eaten?

I am not referring to a cabbage in which the outer leaves are discarded, say when purchased and the outer leaves are damaged/soiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a few places suggesting it's safe (and nutritious) to eat the cabbage stalk/lower leaves:

- [University of Florida](http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/newsletters/hortupdate/hortupdate_archives/2005/may05/SecVeget.html)
- [Gardening Know How](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/cabbage/pruning-cabbage-leaves.htm)
- [Sainsbury’s](https://wastelesssavemore.sainsburys.co.uk/saving-tips/eat-stalks-and-leaves-the-bits-of-vegetables-you-shouldn-t-be-binning)

Answer (score 1):

I am cutting leaves from main stalk and flash cooking them like collard or other greens. Mmmh, very delicious, tasty and similar flavor and texture to other types. I would be careful not to over harvest them though because they are supporting the growth and nourishment of the plant while tha cabbage heads are maturing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can. I like to cut them off and use them in place of flour tortillas to make a breadless sandwich wrap!